# using microsoft graph api list events for a room

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

in microsoft graph api I can obtain a list of rooms

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room
```

how do I view the events for one of these rooms?

looks like my options for events are

```
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events
/groups/{id}/calendar/events
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}/events
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendarGroups/{id}/calendars/{id}/events
```

is the room a "user"? or is it a "group"?  not quite sure given a room find the events that occurring in that room.

Answer (score 0):

`Places` does not have any relationship to `events`.

You should be able to only filter `events` for specific user or group by a location.

Example

```
GET /me/calendar/events?$filter=location/displayName eq 'xxx'
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events?$filter=location/displayName eq 'xxx'
```

Comment: actually may have figured it out.  a room has an email address and then you can use that email address to get the events for the room.  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Bldg650CollinsHallG6ConfRmRmB086@hxxxsxb.onmicrosoft.com/events

Comment: @BryanDellinger Good point. That's probably the best solution.